# how to implement progress bar using angular js for processing multiple request?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have created multiple orders and now I have to confirm all these
orders but until and unless all orders gets confirmed I have to show
progress bar and have to show the status of the ordered confirmed

i.e. suppose i have confirmed 10 orders then 1/10 then 2/10 then 3/10
   ...10/10 status of orders getting confirmed at background.

below i have one example but which doesn't meets to requirement ..

```js
angular.module("app", []) .controller("main", ['$scope',
   function($scope) {
       $scope.value = 10
       $scope.items = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100] }]) .directive('progressbar', [function() {
       return {
           restrict: 'A',
           scope: {
               'progress': '=progressbar'
           },
           controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
               $element.progressbar({
                   value: $scope.progress
               })
   
               $scope.$watch(function() {
                   $element.progressbar({value: $scope.progress})
               })
           }
       } }])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have once used below template:

You can use it:

http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/

Comment: i dont have to use external libraries ...i searched on google and found that using ng-style we can implement progress bar but i am new to angular thats i am not able to implement it ...help apprecieted

Comment: I dont think angularjs provide all this. You need to use otherwise bootstrap progress bar.